# Link a symbol with package name to AS3 class in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have some Flash animations that I need to interact with in Flex.  The first step is to create a class that I can then consume in my Flex application.

The problem is that the only way I can get the symbol to link to the class is if I stuff the .as file in the same folder as the FLA.  Is there a way I can link to the class in a different folder?

I have tried using the integration with Flex, which correctly creates the class in the package I request, but Flash CS5 never links the class to the symbol.

Comment: The issue seems to be with trying to edit in Flex.  It's putting the files in a directory outside of the FLA and they don't get linked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [adding the source folder to the classpath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html#WSB1F410E6-F7BD-443a-97E7-13DE866CA732) in the Flash IDE publish settings?